# Como quebrar a linha após um determinado caracter javascript / vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Possuo um código ao qual me retorna o valor de meu produto:

```
<div
  v-if="product.fields.name"
  class="schott-product-card__name"
  :title="product.fields.name.value"
>
  <b>{{ productTextReplaceBrTags }}</b>
</div>
```

No caso possuo como exemplo o retorno: FIOLAX® clear for syringes

Eu precisava que após usar esse caracter especial ® a próxima letra viesse na linha de baixo, quebrado linha.

Eu sei que seu eu usar assim:

```
productTextReplaceBrTags: function() {
  const doc = this.product.fields.name.value;
  return doc.replace('®', "®\n");
},
```

Terei apenas o retorno do ® porém não existe a leitura do \n.

Como poderia ser feito?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que deve funcionar mudando o estilo da tua tag `<b />` para:

```css
b {
  white-space:pre-line
}
```

Com o `pre-line`, as quebras de linha vão ter o comportamento que você procura.